# How to scale data for nested random effects

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Linear mixed-effects models are sensitive to scaling. Say that I have data on the performance of the students with multiple schools and classes nested in schools, i.e. in R lme4 formula notation something like

```r
performance ~ (1 + covariate | school) + (1 + covariate | school:class)
```

So I assume random intercept and slope for the covariate for schools and classes nested within schools. I have strong reasons to assume clustering within schools and classes, so the assumed nesting is not arbitrary.

Should I scale the data on the school level, or on the class level? What should be considered when making the decisions? Could you point me to some resources discussing this?

*The above example is made-up, but for the actual data that I have, I can see clear differences between the models without scaling vs school-level scaling vs class-level scaling, wherein each case some scaling solves some of the numerical problems that model has, though each of the models has it's own convergence warnings or strange results (e.g. correlations between parameters equal to 0 or 1).*

Comment: Hm... Interesting question (+1). I think it is important to ask why we would scale our data? Is it for the interpretation of coefficients? Is it for the numerical stability issues? Something else? Of the bat, a paper like:[Best-Practice Recommendations for Estimating Cross-Level Interaction Effects Using Multilevel Modeling](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0149206313478188) by Aguinis et al. seems an obvious first stop.

Comment: @usεr11852 numerical issues.

Comment: OK! So.... going back to 1995, Kreft et al. [The Effect of Different Forms of Centering in Hierarchical Linear Models](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26828342/) seems to explore this as: "In nested or grouped data, the option of centering around the grand mean is extended with an option to center within groups or contexts." Their point is that the choice should be based on the theory as model equivalence is not guranteed. I think I also need to note here that centring the response variable entails different issues against centring the explanatory variable.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks, will read both papers.